# Transposing a dataframe with t-function

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to do the transverse of a data frame (a large one about 3750 observation of 3 variables), but I would like to do this :

Original data frame :

```
      activity  level           temp
 1    E             A           10-1810
 2    F             B           10-1810
 3    G             B           10-1810
 4    H             C           10-1810
 5    I             C           10-1810
 6    J             D           10-1810
 ..   ...           ...             ..
```

I would like to get this result :

```
temp       10-1810  10-1810 10-1810 10-1810 10-1810 ..........
activity   E          F       G        H      I      .........
level      A          B       B        C      C      .........
```

My problem is in the t function, when I do the transverse I get always a new data frame as this

```
  row.names x1 x2 x3 x4....................
1   temp ...........
2   activity  .......
3   level     ........
```

I would like to remove row.names (the header ) and make temp the header of the data frame.

Comment: Look into the t and reshape functions?

Comment: Yup, try `t(d)[c(3, 1, 2), ]`

Comment: @jbaums it did not work as i like ,how can i replace the header with time column

Comment: Where is the `time` column in your example?? Do you mean the row names?

Comment: @jbaums sorry i mean the temp column ,i will edit the code

Comment: This really begs the question why? What you really want to do probably has a much better solution. It doesn't appear that you recognize that the main feature of a `data.frame` object is that you can combine different types of data in different columns. This is not possible across rows. The lack of appreciation for `data.frame` is exemplified by your desire to have repeated identical column names. Please explain further what you want to accomplish.

Comment: It's pretty unusual to use repeating values for a header. In your example, `temp` is just a bunch of `10-1810`.

Comment: @jbaums i know that, but i have to do it like that, i need the temp to be the header because i will use a specific algorithm in R who read the temp values

Comment: @John i will edit my code with more detailed

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe is df

```
#normal tanspose
newdf = t(df)

#if you want temp as column name
newdf = data.frame(t(df[,c('activity', 'level')]))
colnames(newdf) = df$temp
```

Comment: `temp` isn't unique, so probably not intended to be colnames. Otherwise, this is the way to go.

Comment: @varjs5 i get an error,  object 'activity' not found, i check my data frame and the name exist!!!!!

Comment: note that `t()` returns a matrix, so if you want it back into a data.frame you need `data.frame(t(df))` and may need to check class of each column.

Comment: i did it @varjs5 but i get error when i would like to view my dataframe, so i run fix(dataframe) and i get all the data ,but there is another problem ,the first values of time are correct and the last one are randomly given

Comment: "the first values of time are correct and the last one are randomly given" @foboss It would help if you could actually paste the output into your question instead of this vague description.